# Understanding android:duration and android:startDelay

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am running a auto play slide show of fragments. In which, each of the fragment should take 1.6 seconds to finish the sliding process. Also, before the previous fragment completes, the next slide should start.

Meaning fragmentA sliding started. It should take 1.6 sec to complete but after 0.5 sec from the time fragmentA started, fragment B should start sliding in. The sliding in process of fragmentB should take the same 1.6 sec. Once 0.5 sec elapsed after fragmentB start to slide, fragmentC should start.

I have created ObjectAnimator xml for each of these fragments like below with duration and startDelay attributes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:valueFrom="1"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="XFraction"
        android:duration="1600"
        android:startDelay="500"
         />
</set>
```

and set android:duration="1600" - to say each fragment should take 1.6 sec to slide in. I put android:startDelay="500" to say that next fragment should start after 0.5 secs from the start of the fragmentA. Is this behavour correct? I am not getting the correct sequence happening in the slide show.

Comment: Maybe you will get better attention if you used/added another tag related to animation. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did simple animation with **ObjectAnimator** in the past. My approach was all coding so that attributes can be changed.
I'll give a code sample.
Code:

```
   ObjectAnimator animateObj;
   TextView animTextView;

   animateObj = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(animTextView, "X", dest);
   animateObj.setDuration(5000);
   animateObj.start();
```

Have fun with this...

Comment: I am animating fragment. With fragments, programmatic approach did not work for me.